# Visual studio debugging - unexpected character instead of objects

Tags: c#, debugging, character

[image]
Hello, I don't know where I should ask this question, but I found hard to continue my C# project while I can't debug it. When I start I see "Unexpected character" instead of objects in my watch. You can see problem on picture linked above. But when I move cursor to objects, I see what they have. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to retype that row. If it won't help, upload your .cs file somewhere and send a link.

Comment: You can tell from the Chinese in the Name column that the debugger exploded rather badly.  Nothing good will happen next.  You left no breadcrumbs to guess how it could have gone so wrong, only sane thing to do is delete that watch and keep your fingers crossed behind your back that this is the only mishap you'll have to deal with.  Disk corruption is one way that this could happen, mangling the hidden .suo file, not a good kind of problem to have either.

Answer (score 0):

`Watch != Locals` window.

Simply delete that entry from watch window (it is probably what is left from previous debug session). It's not necessarily existing variable name (you can insert any text into watch window):

[image]